# Getting around in London without preordering Oyster card

Tags: public-transport, london, oyster-card

In about 20 hours I will be leaving for a trip that will take me to London. My plan for getting around while there had been to get an Oyster card, but at the last moment I discover that they have to be bought in advance. https://www.tfl.gov.uk/travel-information/visiting-london/visitor-oyster-card says:

> It is not possible to buy a Visitor Oyster card when you are in London.

Apparently as a non-resident I was supposed to have planned ahead and bought the ticket by mail order before leaving home.

Do I have any option left for avoiding paying single-ticket fares for everything? Are one-day travelcards are still available without having Oyster?

Comment: You're completely OK to buy a "normal" Oyster card.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can buy Oyster cards at lots of places. I usually do so at the Heathrow tube station myself. What you can't buy are the **Visitor** Oyster cards.

Quoting http://www.tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/buying-tickets you can "*get and top up Oyster cards from*"

- London Travel Information Centres
- Oyster Ticket Stops
- Stations & tram stops
- Emirates Air Line terminals (top-up only)
- The Tramlink Shop (in Croydon)

There only real differences between a Visitor Oyster card vs a regular Oyster card is that they look different, the Visitor Oyster has a £3.00 card fee vs. the £5.00 refundable card fee that the regular Oyster has, and that the Visitor Oyster [entitles you to select discounts](http://visitorshop.tfl.gov.uk/SiteData/Root/File/Special%20offers%20with%20your%20Visitor%20Oyster%20Card.pdf)

Comment: But I am not a UK resident -- doesn't that mean I have to get a visitor card? It looks like non-visitor cards need to be registered with a UK address and a UK bank account to draw funds from.

Comment: No. Registration is optional per https://www.tfl.gov.uk/corporate/privacy-and-cookies/oyster-card and you can "top up" (ie. add more funds) at any kiosk (which pretty much all the tube stations have). I always top up with cash (GBP) but they accept credit cards as well (Visa and MasterCard would be your safest bets)

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't expected to need to go to a "privacy and cookies" page to find that out. The TFL website seems to be trying really hard to hide that from tourists. (I wonder whether the £3 fee that locals don't pay has something to do with that ...)

Comment: Could be lol. When I was first in London I did day passes via travelcards but then I met up with a friend and they showed me how Oyster worked and I've been doing that ever since!

Comment: Speaking as a Londoner the "benefits" of the visitors card look pretty horrifying... I wouldn't want to enter those places. Maybe the only one you'd want is 10% of at Liberty's but you can get VAT refunded if you're not from the UK anyway, which is a a higher percentage anyway.

Comment: This worked well -- accepting. I just wish I had known I was supposed to check out and back in when transferring between underground and NR services, even if the platforms are inside the same set of ticket barriers. Only learned that after it had charged me £5 for each of two "incomplete" journeys, and not counted that towards the daily cap. :(

Comment: @Ben The V&A caff is really nice, but I agree that those are mostly discounts from things you'd have to pay me to go to / eat at.

Comment: @HenningMakholm At most stations (with a few caveats that wouldn't be on most tourists' agenda) you shouldn't have to do that; if and only if you don't have to pass through any gatelines. What was the journey you were making at the time? Did you have a long break at the intermediate station?

Comment: @Muzer: Being a railfan, I'm not most tourists. :) As far as I remember, it was White City to Marylebone NR via South Ruislip, which appears to be too crazy to have any PAYG fare defined at all. [My comment above was probably a bit more affronted than the facts support].

Comment: (But there seems to be a number of less crazy interchanges that don't have PAYG fares either, such as Paddington to West Acton via Ealing Broadway, or Fenchurch Street to Bromley-by-Bow via West Ham).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, yes, it probably didn't like that! I'm surprised about those other nonexistent fares, though. Maybe I should try them and then if I do get charged, contest it and see what happens...

Answer (score 3):

you can buy a visitor oyster card at stansted airport train station but why the heck should you. well only cause the card cost 3 pound instead of 5?! but then you waste money to get to stansted airport so the cheapest method is to get the national rail to london and then go to the tube ticket machine and buy one there for 5 pound. if you want a visitor oyster online it will cost 5.25 with postage and fee plus the PAYG credit.

Answer (score 2):

I made some research (transport for London website and their Facebook page) and I'm going to use my contactless American Express credit card, issued in Chile, for my first trip. My friend who lives in London has some spare Oyster cards, so I'll use one of them later.

American Express cards are always accepted. Mastercard and Maestro cards are almost always accepted; and Visa cards aren't accepted sometimes (weird, huh?). If my Amex doesn't work I'll try with one of my Mastercard cards.

Source: https://tfl.gov.uk/fares-and-payments/contactless/what-are-contactless-payment-cards?intcmp=8610